# Getting "syntax error at or near '('" Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure-postgresql

I am new to SQL. I am getting this error and I'm not sure where is the problem:

```
syntax error at or near "("
```

This is my SQL query for postgres:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS posts;

CREATE TABLE posts (
    title VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
    img VARCHAR(10000),
    source VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(65535),
    tldr VARCHAR(65535) NOT NULL,
    getTime BIGINT(255) NOT NULL,
    category TINYINT(255)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgres doesn't have a `TINYINT` type, it has `SMALLINT`.  And both `BIGINT` and `SMALLINT` don't have a width:

```sql
CREATE TABLE posts (
    title VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
    url VARCHAR(10000) NOT NULL,
    img VARCHAR(10000),
    source VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(65535),
    tldr VARCHAR(65535) NOT NULL,
    getTime BIGINT NOT NULL,
    category SMALLINT
);
```